# Use same variables in multiple neural networks with tensorflow

Tags: python, tensorflow, neural-network, deep-learning

We want to program multiple neural networks in Python with Tensorflow, which have to make use of the same weighting matrices and biases across those networks. We already saw examples of using the same variables in different layers but that is not the case here. Which method is most suitable to use in this situation?

Answer (score -1, accepted):

You could use the same variables across the different networks the same way you share variables with different layers.